# Associate data to default ASP.NET UAM user using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Trying to create a simple MVC application that has basic user account management with social account sign-up.

Created ASP.NET Core 2.2 app with individual authentication, added EF core via NuGet (sqlserver and tools). I have built some basic ASP.NET MVC apps and MVC apps in other languages previously.

I got Facebook login to work per [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Now I'm lost.

There's a "Data" directory with a bunch of code in it already, and the normal MVC directories. However, I don't see the MVC files that would correlate to any of the pages or actions associated with the account management I can clearly access when I launch the application, including `/Identity/Account/Login`, `/Identity/Account/Manage`, `/Identity/Account/Manage/SetPassword`, etc.

While having all of this functionality up and running in minutes is cool, already I'm at a disadvantage of not knowing how or why it works. Searching for anything I would expect to shed some light on this gives me technical documentation that makes my head spin and provides zero enlightenment.

I want to have a collection of data sets ("Books") associated to each user. One User to many Books. Given that the User (account?) model is not in the Models directory of the MVC application I don't think that's where it's supposed to be added. And if it is, I don't know how to create that association with the User.

This is what I'm seeing in a file called `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs`

```
namespace Bookshelf.Data.Migrations
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        ...

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasMaxLength(256);

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
                    .HasMaxLength(256);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                    .HasFilter("[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
            });
```

... and so on, which looks fairly readable, but does not match up to any of the tutorials I've seen so far.

**TL;DR:**

Where/how do I correctly create a new models? Is it [like this in the Models directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (how I'm used to) or is this obsolete?

Either way, how do I correctly associate data with a user given the baked-in user account management for ASP.NET Core 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's a "Data" directory with a bunch of code in it already, and the normal MVC directories. However, I don't see the MVC files that would correlate to any of the pages or actions associated with the account management I can clearly access when I launch the application, including /Identity/Account/Login, /Identity/Account/Manage, /Identity/Account/Manage/SetPassword, etc.

This is because from ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity is being provided as [Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) with the ASP.NET Core project templates. If you want to see those Identity related codes and customize then you have to [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) in your project.

Here is more details about this: [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Moreover if you need ASP.NET Core Identity in MVC format then here is my GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/TanvirArjel/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity) where Razor Page Identity has been converted to MVC in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Somewhat related, when trying the scaffold identity link above, there's no "New Scaffolded Item" option in the add context, using core 2.2 in VS 2017.

Comment: @RandyHall Have your tried: `YourProject>Add>New Scaffolded Item> Identity`?

Comment: Yes. `MyProject>Add` has no `New Scaffolded Item` option, which is weird. I believe I have all the correct packages to be able to

Comment: @RandyHall Update your VS 2017 to the latest version please!

Comment: Ha yup, that was it

Comment: @RandyHall Now is it working? If it is then you can green check my answer please!